# scale texture opengl 2

Tags: opengl, textures, scale

I have a rectangle in opengl 2 and I'm using a texture for it.
It Works, but the texture is repeated over the rectangle, and what I want is to adapt to the size of the rectangle.

I have read in this tutorial about the different parameters you can set to achieve this:
https://open.gl/textures

In my App I am using this:

```
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
```

According to the tutorial this should adapt the size of the texture to fill the rectangle, isn' it?
Any clues about why isn't working that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually stretching a texture over a rectangle works with the texture coordinates. But if you want to repeat it you have to set:

```
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: but I don't want to repeat it... I want it to adapt to the size of the rectangle

Comment: @rreiv23 As i said this works over texture coordinates, you need a rectangle with coordinates from 0 to 1.

Comment: solved, I used coordinates from 0 to 1 for the texture. Thank you.